# fixing html scroll lagging

Tags: html, lag

My HTML scroll is lagging on my site.
Can any one help me please?

#### Here is the code:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
<marquee 
style="direction: rtl"
behavior="scroll" 
direction="up"
scrollamount="2"
onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">

<font size="4">04/02/2015</font>
<br><font size="5"><a style="color:blue" 
href="http://www.vaadness.org/#!revahafinance/c1ob6" target="_parent">
<b>spaciel offer</b></a></font></br>
<br></br>
<p>
<font size="4">28/01/2015</font>
<br><font size="5"><b>MY WEB SITE IS ON LINE!</b></font></br>
</p>
</marquee>
```

Comment: Wow, a `<marquee>` tag. Haven't seen this since 1993 ;). I'm tempted to upvote because of nostalgica.

Comment: I'm amazed you have't seen one in so long. I actively use a marquee on my website http://jackgiffin.com/ to bounce around the logo. Its pretty enticing to visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if by "lagging" you mean stepped, but one way to come over this is by setting a lower`scrollamount`, beside a lower `scrolldelay` (default is 80).
Note that for `scrolldelay` below `60`, you'll need to add the property `truespeed` which is not supported by Chrome.

*Also note that [`<marquee>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) element is **non standard** and **should not be used** in production website!*

> The marquee element is not valid according to the HTML or XHTML specifications. Page authors concerned with validation should not use this tag.

```html
<body style="overflow: hidden">
<marquee 
style="direction: rtl"
behavior="scroll" 
direction="up"
scrollamount="1"
scrolldelay="30"
truespeed
onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">
>

<font size="4">04/02/2015</font>
<br><font size="5"><a style="color:blue" 
href="http://www.vaadness.org/#!revahafinance/c1ob6" target="_parent">
<b>spaciel offer</b></a></font></br>
<br></br>
<p>
<font size="4">28/01/2015</font>
<br><font size="5"><b>MY WEB SITE IS ON LINE!</b></font></br>
</p>
</marquee>
```

Comment: Hi,  by "lagging" i mean that my scroll is taking a lot of time before it appears in my web site. does your answer fix it? do you have a better code  (better then marquee) format to create a rolling text?

Comment: search for "css3 vertical marquee" like this first response : http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/h7SYp/

Comment: +1 for **should not** instead of **is not** because it is still commonly used and will probably never be removed for the fact that JS alternatives have lousy performance, and the marquee tag has support in  MS's own _*cough*_ lousy half-@##  _*cough*_ IE dating back to the dark ages. Like, for example, [this is how the _alternate_ behavior could be implemented in JS](http://jackgiffin.com/beta/bouncing_img_demo.html). Notice how laggy and CPU taxing the webpage is compared to a simple marquee tag.